# What is everybody user & group on Android and why there's no everybody user & group on Linux?

Tags: uid, gid

In Root Explorer I have the option 9997-everybody and 9999-nobody. If I change the owner of any file to everybody:everybody, will it be fully editable by all users? This user does not exist on the Ubuntu/Linux system, does its existence have any meaning?

Comment: It's really just arbitrary. If the whole system is build with the idea that some user group is special, then it's special, otherwise it's not. Android wants / wanted a way for the emulated SD card to be accessible by all apps with the corresponding permission granted, so it has such a group and ownership and corresponding users (apps) are added to the group when appropriate.

Comment: Probably the only numeric id that is "kind of" non-arbitrarily special is `0`. I mean, it's pervasively used for root due to history / convention on anything that is unix-ish, AFAIK.

Comment: out if interest, `nobody` is 65534 in all my linux systems

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah there are probably other conventions like that, but you pretty much can't expect it to be universally special, like nothing really guarantees it is used at all or everywhere. Another example is that, while the wheel group is conventionally speical, but whether it really is pretty much depends on the specific sudo and/or polkit configuration.

Comment: @JaromandaX  Interesting semantics. Right up there with "Who's on First?".